# ASP.NET Ajax Timer count shows wrong

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timer, asp.net-ajax, countdowntimer

I have created an online exam website where i want to implement ajax timer. I have written the code but the problem is I am initializing a session with adding no of seconds for the timer suppose 10 secs. and when the page loads it shows from 6 seconds. So i feel when the page prerender completes the timer has already started thats why it shows from 6 seconds instead of 10 sec

This is the code. If any body can suggest how to display from 10 secs will be greatful.

**aspx file code**

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Remaining Time :"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>        
</div>
</form>
```

**cs file code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["time"] = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
    }
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lblTime.Text != "TimeOut!")
    {
        TimeSpan time1 = new TimeSpan();
        time1 = (DateTime)Session["time"] - DateTime.Now;
        if (time1.Seconds <= 0)
        {
            lblTime.Text = "TimeOut!";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "StartUpScript1", "alert('hello')", true);

        }
        else
        {
            lblTime.Text = time1.Hours.ToString("#00") + ":" + time1.Minutes.ToString("#00") + ":" + time1.Seconds.ToString("#00");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Timer1.Interval = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any response for the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Then you store values in Session, they are unchanged.
Your page loads, and time is already set. After it loads, Timer send the Ajax call to the `Timer1_Tick`, and it gets the time which is outdated.

You need to move your code for the Time setting in the `Timer1_Tick` method, like this:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["time"] == null)
        Session["time"] = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
```

Other approach is to use [javascript or jquery for countdown timers](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/09/jquery-countdown-scripts.html) - this will work as usual, but removes page postbacks to the server.